# Printing Avery labels from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, printing, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, label

I'm trying to dynamically generate and print Avery labels from an ASP.NET MVC 2 application. The labels will be limited to about 5 or so different templates. I am wondering what the best way for doing this is? The Labels are critical to our application and as such, we need to reduce printing error as much as possible.

I have heard I can go for the kludgey approach and make HTML templates, however there will be numerous printing errors. The better approach I've come across is to print to PDF. Are there any pitfalls for this approach and how difficult is it to implement? Also would I go about doing this?
Does anyone know of any API's or third party software that would take care of this functionality?

Comment: is this intra net application?

Comment: i thing that if your question means to print the page effectively then i recommanded the blueprint framework in css

Answer (score 5):

I also struggled with the HTML/CSS approach due to the inconsistent printing behaviour across browsers.

I created a C# library to produce Avery Labels in PDF from ASP.NET which I hope you might find useful:

https://github.com/wheelibin/SharpPDFLabel#readme

You can add images and text to the labels, and it's easy to define more labels types.

*(I use it for barcode labels, the barcode is generated as an image and then added to the label using this library.)*

Cheers

Comment: If it is helpful to anyone: 
I rewrote the SharpPDFLabel code this week as I needed it to be a lot more flexible (and to work with the most recent iTextSharp).   

https://github.com/finalcut/SharpPDFLabel

I added the ability to specify the contents of each individual label if you want (or to continue creating  a sheet of identical labels too).

Comment: @BillRawlinson Muchas gracias!  SharpPDFLabel doesn't seem to work with .NET 4 while your fork does, so awesome job!

Comment: @BillRawlinson I can't get images to work on the labels. In the label.cs, there is nothing in public void AddImage(Stream img) shouldn't there be something in there to add images to labels?

Comment: There probably should be something @MatthewZourelias but I never needed that feature so I never implemented it.

If you want to submit a pull request I'd be happy to work with you to add it.

In fact, the original image code stuff the original author wrote would probably be easy to convert to use with this.  I just skimmed past that when I forked it because I just needed text labels.

Comment: I ported that little bit of code @MatthewZourelias  I have no idea if it works; I didn't test it.  According to the original documentation you would add an image like so:

```cs
//images
labelCreator.AddImage(myImageAsAStream);
```

If you want to add an image and text, it appears you need to add the image first.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look as CSS Media options.
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

Basically you can target styling to the printer, which can hide all the non essential guff on the page and perform fine tuned layout options.

-- Update: More info on PDF generation:

With PDF's typically you have a PDF engine (and there are a LOT out there) on the server with a template that generates a PDF file, this file is then usually downloaded to the browser via a generic handler. Generating your PDF with an html template on the server should eliminate your browser inconsistencies.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Creating_PDF_documents_in.aspx

I stumbled on this technique that uses the Razor View Engine to generate PDF's ala MVC, looks promosing.

http://www.emphess.net/2010/11/09/create-high-quality-pdfs-with-razor-view-engine-and-latex/

Comment: I've looked into using Html/CSS for controlling the format, however a lot of article mention that Html can lead to inconsistencies across browsers and printers. It seems like the most reliable way, is to print PDF. I don't know how to print to PDF and how to make it adhere to a set template.

Comment: Looks like a good lead. However, I'm concerned when they say "create great pdfs from a console application…" Does that mean that for a user to use this they would have to install it on their workstation?

Comment: Typically it is a library that you simply reference in your project (in this case a web site). But I havent used this specific one myself, so couldn't comment on the specifics, but I cant see a reason why it would work.

Comment: As for barcoding, I am sure it will work. All you do is install a barcode font on the server that is rendering the pdf, then reference it in your style sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Wheelibin's SharpPDFLabel is good if you want to print the same content multiple times on your sheet. If you need to print non-identical labels (i.e. each label on the sheet has different content), [I blogged my MVC / iTextSharp / PDF solution here](http://zootfroot.blogspot.com/2012/02/using-itextsharp-to-generate-avery.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would use iTextSharp to create a PDF file containing the required format.

It is a pretty popular open source PDF library for use in .Net.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Comment: I've heard of them before. Would they allow me to make custom templates and import data to the temples? Also do you if it would have some type of barcoding feature?

Comment: It would require some hand coding, but what you are talking about is certainly plausible.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an intranet application and a small number of concurrent users, I will recommend you to consider using Word Automation. Over the years I have implemented Win32 Apps, Winform and Web Apps that automate Ms. Word and although many will critize the use of it, I personally find that it has its niche and can be very useful and work well if managed correctly. For printing to label, some of the key concerns will be layout, formatting and paging. The beauty of using Word MailMerge, you can design and test all that using Ms. Word. You can then create a template file and from the automation perspective, all you need to do is:

- Open the specific template file (from your 5 templates)
- Specify your data source
- Specify your mail merge option
- Execute the mail merge
- Print the resulting document to printer or save it to PDF (directly if you are using 2007 or later, or print to 3rd party pdf driver)
- Close the document & word app

Another very nice feature of using word automation is your ability to record macro and look into the code. So for example, if you are not sure on how to set the data source/mail merge option above, you can record the macro as you are doing that in the UI. Later, look into the generated VBA code and transpose the same logic in your .NET code to achieve the same processing logic flow.

Here is some info to get you started (based on Word 2003, but the object model is very much the same for newer version)
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx

Comment: Great information! However this will be a cloud based application, with good sized number of users. What the users have access to on their side is unknown, so everything should be done by our app through the browser. Would Word Automation be able to handle something like this?

Comment: Yeah the above response is intended to be implemented on the sever side. Client will not require to have word install

Answer (score 0):

In relation to your question about issues in creating PDF output.  The one thing that often gets us is when we use barcodes.  When we do this and generate a PDF, users sometimes print with settings like "scale to fit page" turned on which could resize the output and cause the barcodes to be unreadable.

Comment: The labels will basically be barcodes with a bit of other human readable information on it, so this is a huge concern. Originally we were look for a barcode label generator that we could embed in our app. Have you heard of anything similar?

Comment: There are many libraries out there to assist with barcode creation.  Some are fonts, others return you a bitmap image of the barcode.  PDF is not out of the question, you just need to ensure that the users don't scale the PDF page.  You may be able to force this when creating the PDF, not sure though.  Another option would be to generate some very generic postscript or pcl, embedding the fonts, and calling them.  This file would then be downloaded by the user and sent to their printer, or by some other means (javascript etc.) that would send this to their printer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe using the @print css media type declarations will be the best overall solution for "imprinting" labels. Experimentation will be required as various printers and layout details could affect the layout but I'm working on a solution which requires this now and am going primarily in that direction. I'll do my best to follow up and let you know how well it works. I need to set our online application to imprint name badges on sheets of Avery 5392 6-up perforated badges.

Answer (score 0):

One idea that comes to mind is to use a [CSS style like this one](http://boulderinformationservices.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/print-avery-labels-using-css-and-html/), and also a library to convert HTML to PDF on the server, so that output is consistent for all clients. I use EvoPDF for the latter; this costs money but there are free options as well.

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved by manipulating the XML in an avery-formatted .DOCX file. No third party components required, and you can modify it to suit any datasource, XML, DataTable, etc.

For information on this, see my blog article "[Printable Avery Labels via ASP.net and Microsoft Word XML](http://www.mylescardiff.com/articles/create_printable_address_labels_asp_net.aspx)".